# Error: browserType.launch: Chromium distribution 'chrome' is not found at /opt/google/chrome/chrome

Tags: docker, playwright

I'm trying to run Playwright tests on Playwright Docker.

To run Docker I've used next command:

```bash
docker run --rm --network host -v $(pwd):/work/ -w /work/ -it mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.40.0-jammy /bin/bash
```

After Docker is running I run the next commands:

```
npm install
npx playwright test --update-snapshots
```

After the last command I receive the next error:

```bash
Error: browserType.launch: Chromium distribution 'chrome' is not found at /opt/google/chrome/chrome
    Run "npx playwright install chrome"
```

After running the command from the suggestion I received the next error:

```
Removing unused browser at /ms-playwright/chromium-1091
Removing unused browser at /ms-playwright/firefox-1429
Removing unused browser at /ms-playwright/webkit-1944
++ arch
+ [[ aarch64 == \a\a\r\c\h\6\4 ]]
+ echo 'ERROR: not supported on Linux Arm64'
ERROR: not supported on Linux Arm64
+ exit 1
Failed to install browsers
Error: Failed to install chrome
```

Maybe somebody knows how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `projects` configuration, it seems that you are trying to run the [branded Chrome](https://playwright.dev/docs/browsers#google-chrome--microsoft-edge) instead of one of the browsers that come preinstalled.

> While Playwright can download and use the recent Chromium build, it can operate against the branded Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge browsers available on the machine **(note that Playwright doesn't install them by default)** [...]

And `Chrome` (not `Chromium`) [is only packaged for amd64](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=677140), installing it in an `Arm64` will not be an easy task to do.

If you have something like this:

```json
{
    name: 'Google Chrome',
    use: {
        ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
        channel: 'chrome'
    }
}
```

Remove the `channel` and let it as:

```json
{
    name: 'chromium',
    use: {
        ...devices['Desktop Chrome']
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot!
Removing "channel: 'chrome'" from the config file helped